# How can I map nested objects using the salesforce apex connector framework

Tags: apex, integration

I am trying to get a value from the JSON response and add it to an External Object field. How to do that with a JSON response with nested objects.

Example of the JSON response:

```
"predictions": {
            "winner": {
                "id": 1189,
                "name": "Deportivo Santani",
                "comment": "Win or draw"
            },
```

What to put instead of the Apex code question marks below for the id of the winner?

```
row.put('predictions_winner_id', string.valueOf(newRow.get('???')));
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the id of the winner from the nested **JSON** object and add it to an **External Object** field in Apex, you can use the `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` method to parse the **JSON** string into a map and then navigate through the nested structure.

Here's how you can do it:

```
// Assuming 'jsonString' contains the JSON response
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
Map<String, Object> predictions = (Map<String, Object>) jsonMap.get('predictions');
Map<String, Object> winner = (Map<String, Object>) predictions.get('winner');
Integer winnerId = (Integer) winner.get('id');

// Now you can put the winnerId into the External Object field
row.put('predictions_winner_id', String.valueOf(winnerId));
```